# Is there a way to alter the attach page to enhance specificity for a particular type of relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova, eloquent-relationship

I have a Laravel 9 project with a Nova 4 admin panel and the following set of relationships: there's the `Attribute` entity that defines a particular attribute (e.g. `Project Type`, `Rating`, etc.). A typical attribute is linked to several values that it can have (e.g. `Project Type 1`, `Project Type 2`, `Project Type 3`). These values are represented by the `Option` entity, thus there's a `one-to-many` relationship between attributes and options. Finally, there the `Contractor` entity, which these attributes can be attached to, so we have a `many-to-many` relationship between contractors and options.

Back to Nova, I wanted to be able to attach options to a contractor I select in the contractors detail page and also to attach contractors to a selected option in the options detail page. Using the `BelongsToMany` Nova class I connected these two entities, but the problem is that when attaching an option to a contractor, it shows only one dropdown with all options available without specifying attributes. Is there a way to have two dropdowns, one for attributes, and another one for options, which would be depending on which attribute has been selected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `BelongsToMany` relation, add your custom fields inside and then hide the original fields like so:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Options')->fields(function () {
    return [
        Select::make('Attribute')
            ->options(\App\Models\Attribute::query()
            ->toArray())
        ),
        Select::make('Options')->dependsOn('attribute', function (Select $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $data) {
            $field
                ->options(\App\Models\Option::query()
                  ->where('attribute_id', $data->attribute)
                  ->get()
                  ->toArray()
            );
      }),
    ];
})->hide(),
```